# How to restrict items in query

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load the data from a sharepoint list:

```
var requestUri = "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Request For Information')/items?$orderby=LTIOV";
```

This code doesn't return anything. Only when I say orderby=LTIOV desc; I get results.
I think maybe I can solve it if I restrict the items to this year. How can I make a query saying `Jaar=today.getFullYear();`

Comment: What type of column is `LTIOV`?  What type of column is `Jaar`?

Comment: Dylan, LTIOV is date column. Jaar is a calculated column representing a Year.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Dylan for setting me up the right track. It is not possible to filter on calculated fields. So I choose a text field for the filter:

```
var requestUri = "/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Request For Information')/items?$filter=substringof('2022',RFI_nummer)&$orderby=LTIOV asc";
```

This code is working for me.